# Open registered url type from command prompt with window style hidden

Tags: c#, windows, command-prompt, window-style

I want to open an url type which I have registered in regedit. Namely:

```
swap://server:port/handle
```

I want to open it with **WindowStyle = Hidden** from command prompt. If I do it in C# it is easy:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.Hidden;
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"url:swap://server:port/handle";
p.Start();
```

However as I said I would like to be able to do the same thing from command prompt. I know how to do it without WindowStyle = Hidden:

```
start url:swap://server:port/handle
```

Is there any flag to *start* which I can set in order to force WindowStyle = Hidden?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this just with cmd, however you can use a simple vbscript to open a batch file with the command you want to run to do this

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run("mybatchfile.bat swap://server:port/handle"), 0, True
```

Then your batch file would look like this

```
start url:%1
```

Comment: I haven't worked with vbscripts before but I suppose it's not too hard. However my command varies from call to call. Is it possible to give the batch file an input? i.e. _swap://server:port/handle_ and just have the batch file run _start url:$INPUT_?

Comment: Yeah, you can use parameters, I have edited my answer. To create the vbscript just save the text as a .vbs file.